# Scanning for hardcoded passwords using Checkmarx

Tags: checkmarx

Currently, we're using Checkmarx for scanning application code. Not sure whether Checkmarx detects/scans any hardcoded passwords inside the source code. Are there any extra configurations that need to be added on the Checkmarx server to detect passwords?

Comment: There is one checkmarx rules to detect this

Comment: Update: Checkmarx now has a dedicated tool for finding passwords: https://github.com/Checkmarx/2ms

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to configure Checkmarx to find hard-coded passwords.

Of course, Checkmarx doesn't know your password, so it can't search for it.
What it **can** do is search for things that seem **like** hard-coded passwords, for example:

- `var password = "ab12"` 
  You declare a variable with a suspicious name and immediately assign a value to it. We can guess the `ab12` is your password.
- `var foo = "mypassword"` 
  You probably chose a very bad password and put it in the code, or the string is a placeholder for your password, and one day you will forget to delete the real password.

Another option is to write a query yourself, you will have to ask the person responsible for Checkmarx in your company, whether you can do this.

But still, how do you plan to write the query? **Will the password be hard-coded inside?**

Comment: be aware this rule is not detected all the hardcoded forms of what we can call a password

Comment: Update: Checkmarx now has a dedicated tool for finding passwords: https://github.com/Checkmarx/2ms